# The fixed header tables are getting issue with horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a demo with Fixed Header Tables. The first table horizontal scrolling is working fine but I'm getting a problem with a second table horizontal scrollbar. When I'm scrolling the horizontal scrollbar of second table the vertical scrollbar area is not fixed. I'm sharing my code.

**Tables Demo:**

```js
// JS
$('#maintalbe .pane-hScroll').scroll(function() {
  $('.pane-vScroll').width($('.pane-hScroll').width() + $('.pane-hScroll').scrollLeft());
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font: 14px/1 Arial, sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pane {
  background: #eee;
}
.pane-hScroll {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  background: green;
}
.pane-vScroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.pane--table2 {
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.pane--table2 th, .pane--table2 td {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 160px;
}
.pane--table2 tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}
.pane--table2 thead {
    display: table-row;
}
.mt-4 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Example 1: Two-Table Structure</h3>
<div id="maintalbe" class="pane pane--table1">
  <div class="pane-hScroll">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>foo</th><th>foo</th><th>foo</th><th>foo</th>
      </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="pane-vScroll">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>2</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>3</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>4</td><td>foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>5</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>6</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>7</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>8</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>9</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>10</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>11</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>12</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>13</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>14</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>15</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>16</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>17</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>18</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>19</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>20</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>21</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>22</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>23</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>24</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>25</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>26</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>27</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>28</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>28</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>29</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>30</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3 class="mt-4">Example 2: Two-Table Structure</h3>
<div class="pane pane--table1">
  <div class="pane-hScroll">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>foo</th><th>foo</th><th>foo</th><th>foo</th>
      </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="pane-vScroll">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>2</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>3</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>4</td><td>foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>5</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>6</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>7</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>8</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>9</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>10</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>11</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>12</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>13</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>14</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>15</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>16</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>17</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>18</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>19</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>20</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>21</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>22</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>23</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>24</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>25</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>26</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>27</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>28</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>28</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>29</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
          <tr><td>30</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because within the `scroll` event handler you select *all* the `.pane-vScroll` and `.pane-hScroll` elements, not just the ones related to the current table being scrolled.

To fix this use the `this` keyword to refer to the element raising the scroll event, then traverse the DOM from that to find the related elements and set only their properties. Try this:

```
$('.pane .pane-hScroll').scroll(function() {
  var vScrollWidth = $(this).width() + $(this).scrollLeft();
  $(this).find('.pane-vScroll').width(vScrollWidth);
});
```

Full example:

```js
$('.pane .pane-hScroll').scroll(function() {
  var vScrollWidth = $(this).width() + $(this).scrollLeft();
  $(this).find('.pane-vScroll').width(vScrollWidth);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 Arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pane {
  background: #eee;
}

.pane-hScroll {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  background: green;
}

.pane-vScroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.pane--table2 {
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.pane--table2 th,
.pane--table2 td {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 160px;
}

.pane--table2 tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}

.pane--table2 thead {
  display: table-row;
}

.mt-4 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Example 1: Two-Table Structure</h3>
<div class="pane pane--table1">
  <div class="pane-hScroll">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>foo</th>
        <th>foo</th>
        <th>foo</th>
        <th>foo</th>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="pane-vScroll">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3 class="mt-4">Example 2: Two-Table Structure</h3>
<div class="pane pane--table1">
  <div class="pane-hScroll">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>foo</th>
        <th>foo</th>
        <th>foo</th>
        <th>foo</th>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="pane-vScroll">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```